# Why does a string parameter change the result?

Tags: c++

When I run the below program using Code::Blocks, the output is

```
1 2 3
8129912 -1 3
```

When I try it using [ideone](http://ideone.com/TWeRsI), I get an unspecified runtime error.

I would expect it to print

```
1 2 3
1 2 3
```

Can somebody explain why the `string` parameter makes a difference?

```
int* foo() {
    int a[3] {1, 2, 3};
    return a;
}

int* bar(string x) {
    int a[3] {1, 2, 3};
    return a;
}

int main() {
    int *p = foo();
    cout << p[0] << " " << p[1] << " " << p[2] << endl;

    int *q = bar("X");
    cout << q[0] << " " << q[1] << " " << q[2] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: your array `a` lives on the stack and once you leave the scope of the function accessing this memory is undefined, you are just lucky that it works with the first because there was nothing else on the stack, while the parameter x goes on the stack

Comment: No one can usefully explain undefined behavior.  It's undefined.  In particular, each of your functions returns a pointer to data that were allocated on the stack, and whose lifetime ended when the function returned.  Dereferencing (both of) those pointers produces undefined behavior.

Comment: _"Can somebody explain why the string parameter makes a difference?"_ That's only secondary. Undefined behavior is appearing in first place because you're returning the address of a value that was allocated locally on the stack.

Comment: if you want to avoid such problems when passing/returning arrays from functions use `std::vector` instead, anyway you want to write c++, not c, no?

Comment: Ok, thanks for your comments. I'll read the duplicate answers carefully.